# HTTPS image URL Parse Backend

Tags: http, https, parse-platform

I am using Parse REST API to retrieve images from Parse backend. When I get image file URL it gives me http:// format. However, I am wondering if it is possible to get the image from Parse in https format. Does Parse backend provide this?

Regards.

Comment: It didn't last time I checked, best to take this question to their forum probably / contact them direct.

Answer (score 6):

After searching the Parse blog and other web sites I come up with a solution where I find it important to share. So the problem is Parse file url is in http format where your web site can generate insecure content due to https.

So the solution is using the trick which is presented Parse official mobile application [AnyPic](http://www.anypic.org). You should replace "http://" with "https://s3.amazonaws.com/". For example if you have file url something like this;

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/b05e3211-bf8b-.../tfss-fa825f28-e541-...-jpg
```

then after replacing you can use the url;

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/b05e3211-bf8b-.../tfss-fa825f28-e541-...-jpg
```

Hope this helps to other people.
Regards